# Suppose that {$|x_n|$} converges to 0. Prove that {$x_n$} converges to 0.

Tags: analysis

In a question previous in this assignment I proved that {$x_n$} $\rightarrow L$ and {$|x_n|$} $\rightarrow |L|$.

So I know that this could factor into the problem.

Proof:
Suppose that {$|x_n|$} $\rightarrow 0$. Then, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \Rightarrow ||x_n|-0| < \epsilon$.

Then from the reverse triangle inequality, we have $||x_n|-|0||\leq |x_n-0|$. These can then be rewritten as $||x_n|| \leq |x_n|$. Then with our knowledge of absolute values, we have that $||x_n||=|x_n|$. Therefore, $||x_n-|0|| = |x_n-0|$, so then $|x_n-0| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. Thuse we have that {$x_n$}$\rightarrow 0$.

Is this valid?

Comment: There is no need to use the reverse triangle inequality: $||x_n|-0| = |x_n|$, so, given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $n \geq N \implies |x_n| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: I would say $| |x_n|-0|=|x_n-0|$ and from the convergence of the $|x_n|$ you obtain the convergence of $x_n$. The problem of your proof is that $|x_n-0|$ is a majorant instead of a minorant of $| |x_n|-0|$.

Comment: Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.